# Finding a tangent vector on a curve that is parallel to a given plane.

Tags: calculus, vectors

The question is the following:

Given the curve $r(a)=<6-a^2,a^3+1,1-a>$ and the plane $x+y+z=\pi$, find all the points where the tangent vector on $r(a)$ is parallel to the plane.

I know finding the tangent vector is the first part of the problem. That would be $T(a)=\frac{<-2a,3a^2,-1>}{\sqrt{(-2a)^2+(3a^2)^2+(-1)^2}}$. But beyond there I don't know how to draw a relationship between the line and plane.

Comment: Do you know what a vector that is perpendicular to this plane looks like?

Comment: It would run next to the plane so that they never intersect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is parallel to that plane if and only if $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0$. Therefore,\begin{align}T(a)\text{ is parallel to the plane}&\iff-2a+3a^2-1=0\\&\iff a=1\text{ or }a=-\frac13.\end{align}

Comment: And in the case that I showed above, you would set it equal to $\pi$ correct?

Comment: No. When I wrote “that plane”, I meant the plane $x+y+z=\pi$. Actually, that $\pi$ doesn't matter. It could be $-e$, $\sqrt[3]2$ or $6^{6^6}$. The answer is the same in all cases, since each of those planes is parallel to all the others.

Comment: That makes sense, Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.